# Is it possible to not use session at all, and just rely on servetcontext, hidden form fields etc?

Tags: servlets, cookies, servletcontextlistener

Seeing as using session and cookies are so unsafe, is it possible to securely use just servlet context variables and hiddenform fields, url rewriting to implement same things that session does?

But will it be equally secure and convenient? Why is this method not used?

I am just trying to avoid cookies! Plus, if I save user details in servlet context variables , will it not work same as cookies, but just in server side?
Is that the reason that cookies are ultimately used,That they are client side?

Answer (score 0):

No, Cookies are different from Servlet Context. ServletContext is singleton per application. Not per user.You should avoid using ServletContext for user specific information because you also need to take care of User Lifecycle such as deleting the User info when he is idle.

If you do not want to use Cookie, the alternatives for session tracking are:

- URL Rewirting
- Hidden Form Fields

But you can make Cookies Secured with the help of following properties:

- **httponly**: On a supported browser, an HttpOnly session cookie will be used only when transmitting HTTP (or HTTPS) requests, thus restricting access from other, non-HTTP APIs (such as JavaScript).
- **secured**: A secure cookie has the secure attribute enabled and is only used via HTTPS, ensuring that the cookie is always encrypted when transmitting from client to server.
- **Domain** : They tell the browser that cookies should only be sent back to the server for the given domain.
- **Path**: They tell the browser that cookies should only be sent back to the server for the given path.

Comment: Okay! But, I am confused about use of formbeans classes. We store all user details in the bean class of the customer/user once we have confirmed that user has entered correct password.
What is the scope of using the functions of this bean?
I presume I have to make :  default class, private data members, default functions in it???

Comment: Will this mean that I can use bean class object to give me user's details throughout servlet and other normal classes too?
What I can't understand is then when does the life of this object ends? And what is its scope??

Comment: Yes because of all this issues. you should avoid using ServletContext. You should use Cookie based session handling with the above properties i have mentioned.